# How to disable automatic loading of entities for EntityType?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm coding a registration Form in a Symfony 4 App.

I have a field ZipCode and field City.
The list of cities and zipcode are in a table named `communes`.
When the user fills up the form, I want him to fill up just his zipcode, and then load the cities with this zipcode in a list.

I did this

RegistrationFormType.php

```
 ->add("codePostal", TextType::class, [
                "mapped"=>false, 
                "label"=>"Code postal",
                ])
 ->add('commune', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Commune::class,
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'placeholder' => "Choisir une ville",
            ])
```

And then in the template i play with Jquery and a Json call to change the list
register.html.twig

```
<script>
let dropdownCommune = $('#registration_form_commune');
dropdownCommune.empty();

$("#registration_form_codePostal").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('app_commune_json_list_communes') }}", // point to server-side PHP script
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      data: this.value
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      dropdownCommune.empty();
      dropdownCommune.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

      $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
        //console.log(entry.departement);
        dropdownCommune.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.nom));
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

This works but my problem is that the `commune` field loads all the cities of the database at first load of the page. This takes a long time and I'm sure there is a way to stop it, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: You should be able to override the behavior by using the [`choices` option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-choices) but you might have problems down the line with validation. Check the [form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) reference and search for how to 'add options dynamically'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Query Builder inside your form and limit the results to 0 with `setMaxResults()` this way:

```
->add('commune', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Commune::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                            ->setMaxResults(0);
                    },
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'placeholder' => "Choisir une ville",
            ])
```

And don't forget to add this use:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried and then when i validate the form i have an error.
"This value is not valid", with a Constraint Violation.

ConstraintViolation^ {#1531 ▼
  -message: "Cette valeur n'est pas valide."
  -messageTemplate: "This value is not valid."
  -parameters: [▶]
  -plural: null
  -root: Form^ {#1079 ▶}
  -propertyPath: "children[commune]"
  -invalidValue: "8420"
  -constraint: Form {#1239 …}
  -code: "1dafa156-89e1-4736-b832-419c2e501fca"
  -cause: TransformationFailedException {#1268 …}
}

Do you have an idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a way do that would be a query that select only the ID and the name of the city and use a froeach in the twig, would be fast.
As a second solution will recommend you to use :

```
   $(window).load(function () {
        //Ajax query 
      beforeSend: function () {
            $('#loading').append('<div id="loading""></div>');
      },
      complete: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
      },
   });
```